# How can I bring this function to give back just one winner?

Tags: swift, function

this function should throw out one winner and two losers but at the moment all three drivers are winners oder losers, I don't know what is not functioning, is it the count of the rounds or the fuel I don't know, what can I do?

```
protocol Car {
    var driver: String {get set}
    var brand: String {get set}
    var model: String {get set}
    var speed: Int {get set}
    var maxSpeed: Int {get set}
    var fuelInLiter: Int {get set}
}

struct RaceCar: Car {
    var driver: String
    var brand: String
    var model: String
    var speed: Int
    var maxSpeed: Int
    var fuelInLiter: Int
    var fuelSpentPerRound: Int
    var backedUpDistance = 0
    mutating func startDriving() {
        print("The \(brand) \(model) is driving with \(speed) km/h")
    }
```

** increasing the speed**

```
    mutating func increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: Int) {
        var increasingSpeed = increasingSpeed
        print("\(driver) is increasing the speed...")
        speed = speed + increasingSpeed
        if speed > maxSpeed {
           print("\(driver) drove too fast, his car crashed")
            stopdriving()
        }
    }
    var hasFuel: Bool {
        fuelInLiter > 0
    }
    func stopdriving() {
        print("\(driver) stops driving....")
        speed == 0
    }
```

** This functions should calculate how much kilometres the driver has completed**

```
    mutating func backedUpDistancing() {
        
        if speed < 100 {
            backedUpDistance = backedUpDistance + 1
        }
        if speed >= 100 {
            backedUpDistance = backedUpDistance + 2
        }
        if speed >= 300 {
            backedUpDistance + 3
        }
    }
    
}

struct Race {
    var location: String
    var lenghtInKm: Int
    var firstCar: RaceCar
    var secondCar: RaceCar
    var thirdCar: RaceCar
    mutating func startRace() {
        firstCar.startDriving()
        secondCar.startDriving()
        thirdCar.startDriving()
        
        var roundNumber = 0
        repeat {
            roundNumber += 1
            print("Round: \(roundNumber)")
            firstCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            secondCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            thirdCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            driving()
            firstCar.backedUpDistancing()
            secondCar.backedUpDistancing()
            thirdCar.backedUpDistancing()
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: firstCar)
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: secondCar)
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: thirdCar)
        } while firstCar.hasFuel && secondCar.hasFuel && thirdCar.hasFuel && roundNumber < 10
            win(raceCar: firstCar)
            win(raceCar: secondCar)
            win(raceCar: thirdCar)
        
        }
            
        
    
    func driving() {
        print("\(firstCar.driver) is driving with \(firstCar.speed) km/h, \(secondCar.driver) with \(secondCar.speed) km/h and /(thirdCar.driver) with \(thirdCar.speed) km/h")
        
    }
    mutating func FuelUsage(drivingCar: RaceCar) {
        var drivingCar = drivingCar
        if drivingCar.speed > 100 {
            drivingCar.fuelInLiter -= drivingCar.fuelSpentPerRound
        }
        if drivingCar.speed > 200 {
            drivingCar.fuelInLiter -= drivingCar.fuelSpentPerRound * 2
        }
        if drivingCar.speed > 300 {
            drivingCar.fuelInLiter -= drivingCar.fuelSpentPerRound * 3
        }
        if drivingCar.fuelInLiter == 0 {
            print("\(drivingCar.driver) loses, his \(drivingCar.model) has no fuel anymore...")
            drivingCar.stopdriving()
            
        }
    }
    mutating func win(raceCar: RaceCar) {
        if raceCar.backedUpDistance >= lenghtInKm {
            var winningCar = raceCar
            print("Race is finished! \(winningCar.driver) has won! Congratulations")

        } else {
            print("\(raceCar.driver) has lost the race...")
        }
    }
    
}


var laFerrari = RaceCar(driver: "Fernaddo Gonzales", brand: "Ferrai", model: "La ferrari", speed: 150, maxSpeed: 350, fuelInLiter: 20, fuelSpentPerRound: 2, backedUpDistance: 0)
var lamborghiniHuracan = RaceCar(driver: "Brad Perry", brand: "Lamborghini", model: "Huracan Evo", speed: 120, maxSpeed: 300, fuelInLiter: 30, fuelSpentPerRound: 1, backedUpDistance: 0)
var dodgeChallenger = RaceCar(driver: "Silvester Brady", brand: "Dodge", model: "Challenger Hellcat", speed: 200, maxSpeed: 450, fuelInLiter: 30, fuelSpentPerRound: 5, backedUpDistance: 0)
var fordMustang = RaceCar(driver: "Michael Schuhmacher", brand: "Ford", model: "Mustang GT", speed: 90, maxSpeed: 300, fuelInLiter: 25, fuelSpentPerRound: 3, backedUpDistance: 0)
var buggatiChiron = RaceCar(driver: "Manny Khoshbin", brand: "Buggati", model: "Chiron", speed: 200, maxSpeed: 400, fuelInLiter: 40, fuelSpentPerRound: 5, backedUpDistance: 0)
var mcLarenP1 = RaceCar(driver: "Justin Fuchs", brand: "McLaren", model: "P1", speed: 50, maxSpeed: 310, fuelInLiter: 15, fuelSpentPerRound: 2, backedUpDistance: 0)
var mcLarenSenna = RaceCar(driver: "Christoph Drescher", brand: "McLaren", model: "Senna", speed: 200, maxSpeed: 450, fuelInLiter: 30, fuelSpentPerRound: 3, backedUpDistance: 0)

var DubaiRace = Race(location: "Duabi", lenghtInKm: 10, firstCar: mcLarenSenna, secondCar: mcLarenP1, thirdCar: laFerrari)
DubaiRace.startRace()
```

Comment: Have you run this in the debugger or used some print statements to see what is happening?

Comment: I'm just at beginner at the moment so I#m not able to debug it, but when I let run it, the result of the print statements is that every of them wins

Answer (score 0):

From my own opinion. To run this somewhat naive race you should change your `startRace` function like the following.

```
    mutating func startRace() {
        firstCar.startDriving()
        secondCar.startDriving()
        thirdCar.startDriving()
        
        var roundNumber = 0
        repeat {
            roundNumber += 1
            print("Round: \(roundNumber)")
            firstCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            secondCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            thirdCar.increasingTheSpeed(increasingSpeed: 20)
            driving()
            firstCar.backedUpDistancing()
            secondCar.backedUpDistancing()
            thirdCar.backedUpDistancing()
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: firstCar)
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: secondCar)
            FuelUsage(drivingCar: thirdCar)
        } while roundNumber < 10 && !hasWinner() && atLeastOnOfThreeCarsHasFuel() 
        
        if hasWinner() {
            // do things to show winner
        } else {
            // all three cars has lost the race. No winner
        }
    }
```

Every round you should check if all three cars are run out of fuel or there is an winner. Then you jump out of the repeat cycle to do your finally job. I'll just leave the implementation of `atLeastOnOfThreeCarsHasFuel` and `hasWinner` function to yourself. I think it's not that hard to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

This function is where you're going wrong:

```
mutating func FuelUsage(drivingCar: RaceCar) {
    var drivingCar = drivingCar
    ...
}
```

Swift structs are value types. When you modify them, that just modifies your copy. You're creating a copy of `drivingCar`, modifying it, and then throwing it away. This doesn't modify the one you were passed.

With value types, you either need to have them modify themselves (move `FuelUsage` into RacingCar), create a new struct and return it, or use an inout parameter. Given the rest of your code, you probably want an `inout` parameter here.

```
func updateCar(_ drivingCar: inout RaceCar) {
   // ... remove the var drivingCar = drivingCar ...
}
```

This shouldn't need to be `mutating` since you don't seem to mutate `self` anywhere.

Then you would call it with `&` to indicate that it's an inout parameter.

```
updateCar(&firstCar)
```

If I were building this from scratch, I would probably move the `FuelUsage` function into `RaceCar.update()`:

```
struct RaceCar {
    // ...
    mutating func update() {
        // Your current FuelUsage, operating on `self`
    }
```

Then it would be:

```
for let car in [firstCar, secondCar, thirdCar] {
    car.update()
}
```

Comment: Okay thank you, now it looks smarter but there are still three winners or losers